# Why does a programme that segfaults on launch, launch normally when "reopen"-ed twice?

Tags: macos, crash, big-sur

I have just upgraded to macOS v11.0.1 (i.e., Big Sur). Among the applications that fail to launch after the upgrade is the Jitsi desktop client v2.10.5550. It segfaults during launch.

However, there is a way to get it to start normally:

1. Launch Jitsi.
2. Wait for it to segfault.
3. Click "reopen" in the macOS Crash Reporter dialogue window.
4. Wait for Jitsi to segfault again.
5. Click "reopen" again.

Then Jitsi starts normally.

By contrast, when launched multiple times via the GUI or the CLI, Jitsi still segfaults every time.

So, I am wondering:

1. How does "reopen"-ing a programme twice via the Crash Reporter differ from launching it 'normally'?
2. Is there a way to launch a programme directly the way the Crash Reporter does when lauching it for the second time?

I have read what I could find about the [Crash Reporter in the Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs), but it doesn't say anything about what happens when a programme is re-opened twice. I tried to research how the macOS Crash Reporter works, but googling for "Crash Reporter" works as well as you would expect. I also searched the Apple Developer forums, but didn't find anything there either.